Canon printer TR4551 can not be seen in Ubuntu 22.04
I have a Canon Pixma TR4551 printer and it used to be detected by my laptop on Ubuntu 22.04. But recently it disappeared from the detected printers and when I try to reinstall the driver from the Canon website (link below), the printer is not detected after running
sudo bash ./install.sh
https://www.canon.de/support/consumer/products/printers/pixma/tr-series/pixma-tr4551.html?type=drivers&os=Linux%20(64-bit)
Also simple-scan and scangear are not able to detect the scanner. I have tried to download the source driver and then to add the printer through the ppd file but I don't see an option for adding the printer manually using the ppd file when I launch http://localhost:631/. I know the IP address of the printer and I could see that the printer is connected to the same Wi-Fi network.
Is there a way to troubleshoot the problem ?

try ''lpinfo -v''

This what I get : network ipps
direct hp
network lpd
file cups-brf:/
network beh
network ipp
network https
network socket
network http
serial serial:/dev/ttyS4?baud=115200
direct hpfax
